# Create conditional for COUNT

Tags: sql-server, count, conditional-statements, having

Forgive me if this has been asked but I have been unable to find a solution for this. I'm using the COUNT function, and would like for all returned values greater than 5 to return as ">5".

It seems that the HAVING clause is the way to go, but I don't know how to make it conditional.

Thanks in advance.

SELECT  DISTINCT 
    Column A 
    COUNT(*) AS VISITS
FROM TABLE A
GROUP BY 
    Column A
ORDER BY 
    Column A

Comment: And this is MySQL...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `case` statement to return the correct label,

```
SELECT ColumnaA, case when count(*) > 5 then '>5' else cast(count(*) as varchar(4)) end as visits
from tableA
group by ColumnA
order by ColumnA
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working. However, I'd like counts of 1 through 4 to display as the number rather than '<5'. I tried CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 5 THEN '>5' ELSE COUNT(*) END AS VISITS but am getting the error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' >5 ' to data type int". Thanks again.

Comment: @kmcnair, you need to do cast , updated the answer, do accept the answer to close out the question.